# Get space for array with malloc

Tags: c++, malloc

Trying to pass pointer for array:

```
class aaa{
public:
    int a ;
    int b ;
    std::string c ;
};


void abc(aaa* a [])
{
    *a = (aaa*)malloc(sizeof(aaa)* 5);
    a[0]->c ="ddd" ;
    a[1]->c ="ccc" ;  //crash
    a[2]->c ="eee" ;
}

int main() {

    aaa * a;
    abc(&a);

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a++->c << endl; 

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a++->c << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

On second array element assignment I have crash. Where is the problem? Does `malloc` not creates enough space?

UPD.

I can't change function `void abc(aaa* a [])` signature because of some reason. It is not mistakable signature even it looks not nice.

I have updated program according recomendations in answers, but I still have crash in getting second array element member:

```
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[1].c << endl;
```

Why? What I do wrong in code below?

```
struct aaa{
public:
    int a ;
    int b ;
    std::string c ;
};


int abc(aaa* a [])
{
    int asize =5;
    *a = (aaa*)malloc(sizeof(aaa) * asize);
    for (int i;i<asize;i++)
    {
        a[i] = new aaa();
    }
    a[0]->c ="ddd" ;
    a[1]->c ="ccc" ;
    a[2]->c ="eee" ;
return asize;
}

int main() {
    aaa * a;
    int asize=abc(&a);

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[0].c << endl;
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[1].c << endl; //crash
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[2].c << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<asize;i++)
    {
        cout << "free "<<i<<endl;
        a[i].~aaa();
    }
    free(a);
    cout << "end"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `new` not `malloc`

Comment: Stop using `malloc` in a C++ program.  You cannot use it for the class you have anyway, since it is not a POD type.  Which begs the question -- who or what recommended doing this?

Comment: No, `malloc` doesn't call constructors. Your `c` object is uninitialized.

Comment: Well, I hardly know where to begin.

Comment: Perhaps look up vectors and references

Comment: It's like "I will read my C++ book on usage of `std::string`, and then pick up my `C` book to learn dynamic allocation".  That's how schizophrenic it looks using C+ idioms and then resorting to `malloc`.

Comment: Can I refer you to the book list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: `a++->c` were my last words before I was exiled into the unknown. I reside there yet still while Bjarne Stroustrup and the rest of the ISO C++ Commitee look down on me, shaking his head.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah `free(a - 2);`

Comment: "Get space for array with malloc" - No! *Don't* use `malloc`. Use `new[]` to get space for an array (if you absolutely *must* do things this way) and then for goodness sake, store that return value into a smart pointer for automatic cleanup. Even better; look up (and use) `std::array` and `std::vector`, and please read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 6):

The problems are multifold:

1. `malloc`ing non-POD types so their constructors don't run (catastrophic)
2. Failure to `free` the things you `malloc` (bad)
3. `malloc`ing in C++ at all (not stylish)
4. Passing `aaa* a[]` when you meant `aaa** a` (valid but misleading)
5. No `#include`s, or namespace qualifier on `cout` and `endl` (invalid testcase)

Here's what your program *should* look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class aaa
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    std::string c;
};


std::vector<aaa> abc()
{
    std::vector<aaa> result;
    result.reserve(3);

    result.push_back({0, 0, "ddd"});
    result.push_back({0, 0, "ccc"});
    result.push_back({0, 0, "eee"});

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const auto a = abc();

    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[0].c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[1].c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!"<< a[2].c << std::endl;
}
```

#### ([Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3955943b662ec5e))

Or, to keep your five up-front element allocations:

```
std::vector<aaa> abc()
{
    std::vector<aaa> result(5);

    result[0].c = "ddd";
    result[1].c = "ccc";
    result[2].c = "eee";

    return result;
}
```

I strongly suggest forgetting everything you know about C, when you write C++.

Comment: Note, you don't need the `.reserve(3)` call.

Comment: @melpomene: You do if you want to pass code review ;)

Comment: Why? And if you need to preallocate, why not just `std::vector<aaa> result(3);` in the first place?

Comment: @melpomene: Shhhhh don't bring facts into this

Comment: @melpomene You should be commending him for his restraint ;)

Comment: @RichardCritten: Meh if my restraint were working properly today I wouldn't be here ;0

Comment: Probably from OP

Comment: Slight off-topic: welcome back lrio. I hope you continue answering.

Comment: @Ron: Worry not, only a momentary lapse 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `malloc`, but you still need to call constructors, for this you need `new`, this defeats idea of using `malloc`.

```
const int asize = 5;

void abc(aaa*& a)
{
    a = (aaa*)malloc(sizeof(aaa) * asize); // you need to release memory later
    for (int i = 0; i < asize; ++i) {
        new (a+i) aaa(); // you need to call constructors to intialize string
    }
    // now you can use strings
    a[0].c = "ddd";
    a[1].c = "ccc";
    a[2].c = "eee";
}

int main() {
    aaa * a;
    abc(a);

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << a[0].c << endl;
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << a[1].c << endl;

    // finally you need to call destructors
    for (int i = 0; i < asize; ++i) {
        a[i].~aaa();
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

After showing you how you can make it work, i would like to propose another solution. If you care about memory and don't want to use `std::vector`, you can use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<aaa[]> data;
data = std::make_unique<aaa[]>(asize);
data[0].c = "text";
cout << data[0].c;
// no need to manually release memory
```

EDIT:
As of updated question. If you really want to pass array of pointers then you can do the following:

```
const int asize = 5;

void abc(aaa* a[]) {
    // If array is really big, then you probably should preallocate memory and call placement new for every element.
    for (int i = 0; i < asize; ++i) {
        a[i] = new aaa; // again, you have to release memory 
    }
    // now you can use strings
    a[0]->c = "ddd";
    a[1]->c = "ccc";
    a[2]->c = "eee";
}

int main() {
    aaa * a[asize];
    abc(a);

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << a[0]->c << endl;
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << a[1]->c << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < asize; ++i) {
        delete a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It would be very nice if you could use unique_ptr instead of raw pointer.

Comment: Except you leaked it all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, right, i mentioned it in the comment:)

Comment: Mm. Well, while I can't commend the approach or advise recommending this to the OP, you've certainly come up with an otherwise valid solution :P BTW I know it looks like you're "calling constructors" but you're not really; there is no syntax to explicitly "call a constructor". Nitpicking though as the end result is the same, particularly in the placement new case.

Comment: If we're going full C++, shouldn't it be `static_cast<aaa *>(malloc(...))`?

Comment: Actually I do wonder whether alignment constraints are satisfied here

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hmm, it depends on how std::string implemented, good point!

Comment: Alignment? Probably chaotic neutral.

Comment: @user4581301 #igotthatreference

Comment: I can't escape from function `void abc(aaa* a [])` signature. Since that reason I have updated question body with updated code that crashes in the same place.

Comment: @vico hope after my two answers it is more clear for you:)

Comment: In my live case `main()` not knows what is size of array. So, I can't use line `aaa * a[asize];`. `abs()` should define size and fill array.

Comment: @vico you can't do anything in this case, because parameter of `abc` is an array of pointers and you can do what you want with pointers but not with array. I suggest you to close this question and start new, only describe the real problem, why you do you need such function signature at all, probably the problem is at another layer.

Comment: I would like to understand why I can't do with pointer to array of pointers and can with pointer. Pointer to array is still pointer and contains not for example `aaa` type, but `[]` of `aaa` that might be retrieved if you know `[]` size. But yes, this is new question.

Comment: @vico you don't have `pointer to array of pointers` your function accepts just `array of pointers`, so it can work with this array, but not change it. Look into my first code sample, i don't pass just a pointer, but reference to a pointer to be able to change this pointer, without reference, i would be able to change only pointee, not pointer.

Comment: @Yola: _"your function accepts just array of pointers"_ Actually it doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit about alignment: [the C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#2) redirects to the C one, [which says](https://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#7.20.3) that *"The pointer returned [...] is suitably aligned so that it may be [...] used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated [...]."* So this is fine as far as alignment is concerned :)

Comment: @Quentin: Great :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `aaa *arr[]` - array of pointers, isn't it?

Comment: @Yola: I'm afraid not. It is automatically translated to `aaa** arr` and actually has nothing to do with arrays. We inherited this ghastly nonsense from C, sorry.